# String length and character validation using Java 8 stream API

Tags: java, validation, java-stream

> Find if an input String is valid - the criteria is String `length` greater than 5 and characters must be `a-z, A-Z or 0-9`.
>
> Valid strings: `aA12Z22`, `qwerty`, `ABCDEF0`
>
> Not valid: `13A`, `12CrW#`, `@**=_+`

I am trying to get it right using `Java 8 streams`. I have a solution here. The question - is there a better way of doing this (using `streams`)?

```
boolean valid = Stream.of(string)
    .flatMapToInt(s -> {
        if (s.length() < 5) return IntStream.of(42); // 42 is a '*' char
        else return s.chars();
        })
    .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
    .allMatch(c -> Character.isLetterOrDigit(c));
System.out.println(valid);
```

Comment: Why not just use regex: `string.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]{5,}")`? Streams seem unnecessary, hard and inefficient.

Comment: Can you explain why do you want to do it using stream api? what benefit does it offer compared to regex ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I'd use regex:

```
boolean valid = string.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]{5,}");
```

But if you're going to use streams, I'd do it like this:

```
boolean valid =
    s.length() >= 5 &&
    s.chars().allMatch(Character::isLetterOrDigit);
```

Noting that `Character.isLetterOrDigit` may match more characters than you want (e.g. `१२३`). You could additionally check that `c < 128`.

Comment: smart solution !

Comment: Both the solutions answer my question. The first is precise and compact (and more efficient as you had mentioned) and the second is easily readable and maintainable. Thanks for replying.